# Simultaneous Audio Streaming on Fire TV

Tags: android, audio-streaming, amazon-fire-tv

I have an Android app that can stream two audio streams simultaneously. Do Fire TV devices support simultaneous streaming?

Comment: does it work today on a regular Android 4.2 device? if so... should be okay as that's what the device is based on. How do you handle multiple players currently?

Comment: Yes, it works on smartphones, but did not work on Fire TV. I will try to figure out whethe it is a limitation of the device. I have two different services streaming audio simultaneously.

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they do. I am working on a Fire TV application that can play two MP3 streams simultaneously.